# PHP Form issue - using MySQL database on PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am a .NET guy. I am asked to fix a PHP form issue, can you please help me to figure-out db connection issue in the code if any.

I have a page connect.php having following code:-

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("100.100.10.92","CountryCabs_123","Country!23Cabs_123","newdb1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Now I've a form with following infomation:-

```
<?php error_reporting(0); include("connect.php"); ?>
<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<div class="main">
<div style="width:100%;">

<div id="div2">
<div class="head1">Book Your Cab</div>
<div class="content1">

<form name="bookcab" id="bookcab" method="post" >
<table width="100%">
<tr >
<td colspan="4"><div class="titlehead">Local Booking</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><div><span
style="color:#FF0000">*</span> Mandatory Feilds</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"> <div class="border1"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="15%">CITY</td>
<td width="34%"><select id="size3" name="from3">
<option value="Pune">Pune</option>
</select></td>
<td width="12%" align="right">PACKAGE<span
style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
<td width="39%"><select id="size4" name="packages">
<option value="0">Hr/Kms</option>
<?php $select= mysql_query("select * from local_packages");
$i=1;
while($sel= mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo
$sel['package_name'];?>"><?php echo $sel['package_name'];?></option>
<?php $i++;}?>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="15%">Cab Type <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</td>
<td width="39%"><select name="cabtype" id="cabtyp" >
<option value="0">CabType</option>
<option value="Hatchback">HatchBack</option>
<option value="Compact">Compact Sedan</option>
<option value="Sedan">Sedan</option>
<option value="MUV">MUV</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4"> <div class="border1"></div></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="padding-left:5px"><h4>When</h4></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px">Pickup Date<span
style="color:#FF0000; margin:0px 22px 0px 0px">*</span> :&nbsp;</td>
<td> <span class="k-textbox" style="width:200px"><input
name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="tcal" value="<?php echo
$_SESSION['date'];?>"/></span></td>
<td width="28%"><span style="padding-left:20px">Pickup Time <span
style="color:#FF0000; margin:0px 35px 0px 0px">*</span> :</td>
<td><input name="timepicker" id="timepicker" value="<?php echo
$_SESSION['time'];?>" style="width:200px"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// create TimePicker from input HTML element
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker();
});
</script></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"> <div class="border1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px">Pickup Address <span
style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</td>
<td colspan="3"><select name="pickup" id="pickup"
onchange="selectAdd(this.value)" style="width:200px">
<option value="Home">Home</option>
<option value="Office">Office</option>
<option value="Railway">Railway Station</option>
<option value="Airport">Airport</option>
</select></td>
</tr>


<?php $select= mysql_query("select * from member where
pkey='".$_SESSION['regId']."'");
$selected= mysql_fetch_assoc($select);?>
<tr>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><textarea name="pickupaddress"
class="k-textbox" style="width:300px; height:100px" id="pick"><?php
echo $selected['per_address'];?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="4"><div class="border1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="padding-left:5px"><h4>Traveller's
Details</h4></td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php $select= mysql_query("select * from member where pkey=
'".$_SESSION['regId']."'");
$list= mysql_fetch_assoc($select); ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" ><input type="radio" name="self"
value="self" onclick="addDetails('<?php echo $list['firstname']."
".$list['lastname']?>','<?php echo $list['mobile']; ?>','<?php echo
$list['email'];?>','<?php echo $list['company'];?>')"
checked="checked">
Booking For Self
<input type="radio" name="self" value="other"
onclick="addDetails('','','','')">
Booking For Others</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="18%" style="padding-left:5px">Name
<span style="color:#FF0000 ; margin:0px 52px 0px 0px"> * </span>:</td>
<td><span class="k-textbox" style="width:200px">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"
value="<?php echo $list['firstname']." ".$list['lastname'];?>" >
</span> </td>
<td width="28%"><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px
20px">Mobile No.<span style="color:#FF0000; margin:0px 47px 0px
0px">*</span> : </span></td>
<td width="38%"><span class="k-textbox" style="width:200px">
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"
value="<?php echo $list['mobile'];?>" onKeyPress="return
isNumberKey(event)"><script type="text/javascript">function
isNumberKey(evt)
{
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
return false;

return true;
}</script>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" style="padding-left:5px">Email ID
<span style="color:#FF0000; margin:0px 42px 0px 0px">*</span>: </td>
<td width="18%"><span class="k-textbox" style="width:200px">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"
value="<?php echo $list['email'];?>">
</span></td>
<td width="28%" ><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px
20px">Company </span><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px
57px">:</span></td>
<td width="38%"><span class="k-textbox" style="width:200px">
<input type="text" name="company" id="company"
value="<?php echo $list['company'];?>">
</span></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px">Lead<span style="margin:0px
0px 0px 69px">:</span></td>
<td colspan="3"> <select name="lead" id="lead" style="width:200px">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="Website">Website</option>
<option value="Referal">Referal</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
<option value="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="padding-left:5px"><div id="planes"
style="display:none;"> Flight No.:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="k-textbox"
style="margin:0px opx 0px 69px">
<input type="text" name="planess" id="planess"
value="" style="width:195px">
</span> </div>
<div id="train" style="display:none;"> Train
No.:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="k-textbox"
style="margin-left:50px;width:200px" >
<input type="text" name="trainNo" id="trainNumber"
value="" style="width:195px">
</span> </div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left:5px">Special
Requirements<span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 18px">:</span></td>
<td colspan="3" >
<textarea class="k-textbox" style="width:300px;
height:100px" id="requ" placeholder="Eg: Clean and Ac Car"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ></td>
<td colspan="3">
<input type="button" name="book" id="book" value=" Book "
onclick="confirm_book_local()" style="float:inherit"
class="btn"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>


<!--------confim------->
<div style="display:none;" id="div3">

<div class="head1">Booking Details</div>
<div class="content1">
<form name="confirmation" id="confirmation" method="post"
action="submit-form-local.php">
<table width="100%" height="auto" border="0" cellpadding="6"
cellspacing="0" >

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="22%"><strong>Traveller's Name</strong></td>
<td width="2%"><strong>:</strong></td>
<td width="72%"> <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname"
style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:400px;"
readonly/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span style="margin:0px 30px 0px 0px; font-weight:bold">Email
ID</span> </td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold" ><input
type="text" id="dmail" name="dmail" style="border:none;
background-color:transparent; width:220px;" readonly></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span style="margin:0px 30px 0px 0px;font-weight:bold">Mobile
No</span>   </td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold" >
<input type="text" id="dmobile" name="dmobile"
style="border:none ;background-color:transparent; width:150px;"
readonly/>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span style="margin:0px 30px 0px 0px;font-weight:bold">Cab
Type</span> </td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold" >
<input type="text" id="dcabtype" name="dcabtype"
style="border:none ;background-color:transparent; width:150px;"
readonly/>
</span></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td ><h4>City</h4></td>
<td ><strong>:</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" value="Pune"
style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Pickup Address</h4></td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="dpick" id="dpick"
style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly/></td>
</tr>

<td><h4>Departure Date</h4></td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="Pdate" id="Pdate"
style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly/></td>
</tr>
<td><h4>Departure Time</h4></td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="Ptime" id="Ptime"
style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><h4>Special Requirements</h4></td>
<td><strong>:</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" id="special" name="special"
style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept">
I have Read And Accept The <a href="termsconditions.php"
target="_blank">Terms And Conditions</a></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pay" value="cos"
onchange="display_message(1)" checked="checked">
<strong>Cash On Service</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="pay" value="pay_now"
onchange="display_message(2)">
<strong> Pay Online</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td id="m1" style="display:none; color:#FF0000">Extremely Sorry!
Online payment mode is temporarily down, please select cash on
service as of now. We regret for the inconvenience you had.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="confirm" id="con1"
value="Confirm" style="float:left;margin-right:20px;" class="btn"
onclick="validCondition()">
<input type="button" name="back" value="Back" style="float:left;"
class="btn" onclick="bookback()"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style="margin-left:20px">You can cancel your booking
anytime. Please read our <a href="cancellation_ privacy.php"
target="_blank">cancellation policy</a> for more details.</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="hiddencarId" value="<?php echo
$_GET['id'];?>"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php include('footer.php');?>
<script>
document.getElementById('li05').classList.add('active');
</script>
```

There is some user accessibility issue on database, we are using GoDaddy. I verified the credentials on MySQL Workbench i can connect database. Can you please verify if any issue in code.

Comment: thanks for quick response Arif. Is it easy to fix?

Comment: sure i'll update you Arif. It was user accessibility issue on the database. Do you think it was cause of not using '$link' and mysqli .

Comment: Arif, i can successfully connect GoDaddy hosted MySQL database from my local PC MySQL Workbench using the credentials written above. I'm going to try out your suggestion after lunch. Thank you.

Comment: Arif, i understand security risk :) these credentials are already mixed smartly.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing *mysqli* with *mysql*. Should be using *mysqli* only instead of *mysql*, which is already deprecated. And when using *mysqli*, it is best (and a must) to be doing prepared statement on it to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

I'll be doing the first drop down for an example, so you can have an idea and do the rest.

```
<select id="size4" name="packages">
  <option value="0">Hr/Kms</option>
  <?php

    $select= "SELECT package_name FROM local_packages";

      if($stmt=$link->prepare($select)){

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($packagename); /* BIND THE RESULT */

        $i=1;

        while($stmt->fetch()){ /* FETCH RESULTS */

          printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$packagename,$packagename);

          $i++;

        } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

        $stmt->close();

      }

  ?>
</select>
```

I still included the `$i` variable. Maybe you have other purpose for it.